# List of number of knots distinguished by Alexander polynomials

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Is there a list of numbers of how many knots are disinguished by their Alexander polynomials? Up to certain crossing numbers, or for each crossing number individually. I`m trying to get a feel for how likely it is to be able to tell apart a knot just based on one polynomial. Of course it is possible to count by hand, but for the higher crossing numbers...

I also wondering whether it is possible to get this numbers using the Knottheory package for Mathematica using NumberOfKnots[n].

Comment: I actually just managed to do it with Knottheory it and will post the number of attained polynomials.

Comment: Please post your results, including the exact input and output. I'm interested, but I don't use Mathematica.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/?

Comment: In general, the Alexander Polynomial seems to be one of the weakest polynomials. It is easy to come up with knots with trivial Alexander polynomial, or pairs with the same Alexander polynomial, just by ensuring the Seifert forms are the same. The Seifert form only sees the linking numbers of bands of a Seifert surface, so it is easy to come up with lots of different examples just by keeping the linking number the same. On the other hand, it is hard, if not impossible, to construct knots with trivial Jones Polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The table gives the number of occuring Alexander polynomials if the knots are regarded for each crossing number seperately. This is according to mathematica and Knottheory package, it might be good to check with other tables.

[image: Number of occuring Alexander polynomials if the knots are regarded for each crossing number seperately]